# Angular carga los objetos pero no se muestran hasta que hago click en otro lado

Tags: angular

Carga todos los datos ok desde el back-end, pero cuando hago click en otro lado, por ejemplo dentro del mismo slider recién me muestra los resultados. ME pasa con todas las llamadas que hago en mis códigos.

[edito]
Me esta pasando en todos los observer, incluso cuando cargo algún file me pasa lo mismo. Esto va mas alla del código ya.

carousel.component.ts

```
sliders: Slider[] = [];

constructor( private sliderService: SliderService){
    
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.cargarSliders();
}


cargarSliders() {
  this.cargando = true;
  this.sliderService.cargarSliders()
      .subscribe( sliders => {
        this.cargando = false;
        this.sliders = sliders;
        console.log("sliders:",sliders);
  });
}
```

carousel.component.html.ts

```
<section class="wrapper">
    <!--- * carrusel * ---->
    <div *ngIf="sliders" class="carousel flex-row">
      <div *ngFor="let slider of sliders;" >
          {{ slider.nombre }}
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

slider.service.ts

```
cargarSliders(): Observable<Slider[]>{
        const url = `${ base_url }/sliders`;
        return this.http.get<{ok: boolean, sliders: Slider[] }>( url, this.headers )
                  .pipe(
                    map( (resp: {ok: boolean, sliders: Slider[] }) => resp.sliders )
                  );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucione mi problema. En mi caso tenia este component dentro de un padre llamado slider. Que tenia estos parametros:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-slider',
   templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css'],
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

quitando esto pude solucionar el problema:

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

no tengo claro porque generan conflictos, estaba usando ese parámetro para usar un select dinámico, toca buscar otro modo.

Si alguien me puede iluminar sobre esta cuestión estaría mas que agradecido.